# How to force Windows to create the running user's profile directory

Tags: c#, windows, profile, impersonation, user-profile

I am having an issue with a process being run, where the profile directory of the process' user has not yet been created.

To explain, here are the details of how this is happening:

We run a large distributed server grid, and are using (parts of) DataSynapse to execute processes on this grid.  For those familiar with DataSynapse, the Engine is configured to run the particular service with "RunAs", where we use a certain AD domain service account for the service processes.  I believe the problem is that DataSynapse, when running the process under "runas", does not set the `LoadUserProfile` flag (nor should it).  Whatever the precise reason, if the "runas" service account (and AD domain account) has never logged on to some of the grid machines, then those machines will not have the user profile directory for the account.

For those not familiar with DataSynapse, here is a more generic explanation.  On each machine on the grid, there is a process running, I'll call it `dsService`, and it runs under the credentials of the local machine's system account (or some similar account with elevated credentials).  The process `dsService` will spawn a child process, say `childProcess`, but it runs `childProcess` under the credentials of our AD domain account, which I'll call `serviceUser`.  There are thousands of machines on the grid, and typically they are never logged on to manually.  In particular, the profile directory `C:\users\serviceUser` may not initially exist.  Once it is created once, there are not further issues.  But if new nodes are added to the grid, typically they will not have the `C:\users\serviceUser` initially.  The problem is that when the `dsService` spawns `childProcess`, `C:\users\serviceUser` does not get created, and we need it.

I *believe* that this is because `dsService` does not set the `LoadUserProfile` flag to true when spawning `childProcess`, though I am not certain.

In any event, `childProcess` is a (.net) process (running as `serviceUser`) under our control, and **I would like to know if there is a way (in C#) that `childProcess` can force the OS to create the running user's profile directory** `C:\users\serviceUser` when it determines that it does not yet exist?

Edit:
Experimentation has confirmed that if one starts a process under another user ID, and the user's profile directory is not there (more specifically, if the user's *local profile* has not been created yet - merely deleting a pre-existing profile directory creates a different situation, one we're not interested in anyway), then (1) the profile directory (and one presumes, the local profile) gets created if the process is started with the `LoadUserProfile` set to true; and (2)  the profile directory (and one presumes, the local profile) does NOT get created if the process is started with the `LoadUserProfile` set to false.  This makes sense, and is as one would expect.

Related post: stackoverflow.com/q/9008742/1082063

Comment: Do you have to use a "User Directory?"  This seems like the type of application that should be saving its data in its own program directory, or just in a directory that it creates elsewhere on the hard drive...

Comment: No, you can't do this from the user's context.  If DataSynapse doesn't provide an option to create the user profile, and you can't bypass the requirement for the user profile to be present, you'll need to arrange for some code to run as local system or another suitably privileged account.

Comment: First, though, you should test whether simply creating the profile is in fact sufficient.  If your code requires the profile to be *initialized* rather than merely *loaded*, you've got a harder problem.  The only way to initialize a profile is for the user to log on interactively.

Comment: @Elemental-Pete: the same application runs under different user ID, and the data for each user ID must be kept separate and hidden from the other ID's.  This is an institutional audit requirement.  While this could be done with special directories, the ID's under which the the process runs cannot have permissions to create (or lock down) dirs outside their own profile.  While we could create a special directory for each such user ID, it puts us no further ahead: we would still need to do preliminary setup on each grid engine, and in that case, may as well just ensure the profile is set up.

Comment: @Harry-Johnston: we have tested that it is sufficient to simply create the profile.  In fact, until now we were running without the profile ever being created and just using special directories, as per Elemental Pete's suggestion above.  All we are trying to do is avoid needing to set up (specially permissioned) directories on each grid machine by using the profile directory, which, when created, has the permissions we need.

Comment: @Harry-Johnston: "No, you can't do this from the user's context" - could you point me to some documentation?  Thanks.   BTW, it is not a requirement for the _user profile_, per sae, to be present.  As I said in my previous comment, we really don't need the user profile (e.g. we never touch the user's registry, etc.), just the user's profile directory - but I do understand they come as a package essentially.

Comment: Um.  On second thoughts, I probably shouldn't have ruled out the possibility that some trickery would be possible.  For example, if you attempt to encrypt a file on a network server, that causes a user profile to be created on the server.  (That particular case doesn't help you, it's just an example of the sort of oddity that could conceivably give you a solution.)  Personally I'd recommend doing things the straightforward way if at all possible.

Comment: @Harry-Johnston: Very much agreed about avoiding trickery.  It's not too difficult to ensure ahead of time that the user's profile is created.  I just thought there might be a straight-forward, transparent method of creating the user profile, e.g. by calling the LoadUserProfile function (which seems not to be available only in c# - ouch).

Comment: You need admin privileges to call LoadUserProfile.  I don't suppose the child process knows what the corresponding account password is?  If it did, it could call CreateProcessWithLogonW.

Comment: final comment: this link daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/225868/‌​… has lots of useful code

Answer (score 0):

If the running account has admin privileges, the following code will cause the creation of the running account's profile, including its UserProfile directory.  Without admin, I don't know if it is possible:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int CreateProfile(
    [In] string pszUserSid,
    [In] string pszUserName,
    System.Text.StringBuilder pszProfilePath,
    int cchProfilePath);

....
public static string getUserProfilePath()
{
    string userProfilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userProfilePath) || !Directory.Exists(userProfilePath))
    {   //This will only work if we have admin...
        var pathBuf = new System.Text.StringBuilder(240);
        var Up = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current;
        if( 0 == CreateProfile(Up.Sid.ToString(), Up.SamAccountName, pathBuf, pathBuf.Capacity) }
        {
            userProfilePath = pathBuf.ToString();
        }
    }
    return userProfilePath;
}
```

If anyone can tell me how to do this when the account is not admin, they will get their answer accepted as the correct answer.  Until then, this at least gives others some idea.